# How can I add iptables rule on particular event (HTTP/1.1 302 Found)

Tags: iptables, vpn, tcpdump, tomato

My Tomato based router has two interfaces
Eth0 - direct connection
Tun1 - vpn

Sometimes some websites return "HTTP/1.1 302 Found" and when that happens, I want to add iptables rule to use Tun1 instead of Eth0 for that particular IP.

I can not figure out how to catch "HTTP/1.1 302 Found" response on router and how to use it as a trigger for IPTABLES rule. Should i have tcpdump 24\7 or there are better ways? Any input will be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do this, aka what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is anything ready to implement this kind of behaviour.

In order to accomplish this, you need to consider the following points:

1. This is only possible with HTTP connections, as it requires being able to read the plain-text version of data. In HTTPS the data is encrypted.
2. One needs to have a mechanism which reads the traffic and implements HTTP protocol parsing and finds out destination from the `Location` HTTP header.
3. One needs to parse the URL to extract the domain from `Location` header, and then perform an IP address lookup for that domain.
4. One needs to add the IPTables NAT rule for IP address found in step 3 to the kernel's firewall tables.

In conclusion, this would need many different components to implement the feature, and I don't think no-one has implemented it.